# Custom class to an overall ANTD table in react

Tags: reactjs, antd

I wanted to know whether it is possible or not to attach a custom class on our overall antd table in React. If yes then how could we do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "custom class" you mean a CSS class. Since an antd `<Table />` is an ordinary JSX component, you can specify the CSS class (or even style) as for any other component:

```
<Table
  className={"myClass"}
  style={{color: "#0000FF"}}
  ...
/>
```